# Restoring a Bitcoin Core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I have a wallet.dat file from an old computer which was last accessed around February 23, 2012 which I need to restore into a newly installed Bitcoin Core program on a new computer.

1. Can I just install the latest version of Bitcoin Core on the new computer (making sure the program is not running) and copy the wallet.dat file over the new empty wallet.dat file in the C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallets  folder and restart Bitcoin Core?
2. Must I install the same old version of Bitcoin Core I had previously had installed on an old Windows Vista machine back on February 23, 2012 prior to restoring the wallet.dat file as described above?   If so, what files will help me figure out exactly what version of Bitcoin Core I had been running back on February 23, 2012 and where can I find that version of Bitcoin Core to install on Windows 10?

Thank you!